# Phonegap: Set base href but still Include local JS/CSS/Images

Tags: cordova

I am making remote ajax calls in my phonegap index.html file and the response is an html snippet including relative references to javascript, css and image files on the remote server. In order for the relative references to function properly I include a `<base href="http://myserver.com" />` tag in my index.html file.

This works as expected.

However, I would like to also include local CSS/JS/Image files stored in the www directory of my Phonegap Application. As I set the base href to http://myserver.com I can no longer include them using relative URLs (e.g. `<script src="phonegap.0.9.5.js"></script>`).

My question is: How can I reference these files?

I am hoping that something like this will work (as I am still posting this question, it is not quite that simple):
`<script src="file:///www/phonegap.0.9.5.js"></script>`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Local images I reference with

```
./assets/img/img.png
```

and then when I am getting something on the server I remove the starting dot. So when I am testing my application, I use an asset_path variable that either has the dot or not (in your case you could put the full URL).

Comment: Me neither. BTW, can you explain more how you use the asset_path variable and set it?

Comment: check the useragent or the device for what sort of mobile you are on, and set it accordingly if I remember correctly

Answer (score 0):

`alert(document.location.href)` inside the index.html gives me the absolute path on Android.

Maybe it works on iOS too.

Answer (score -2):

You was almost there. Just use absolute paths instead of relative ones (for windows, as was my case):

```
<script src="file:///C:/webservers/home/www/phonegap.0.9.5.js"></script>
```

Comment: great, but what is the absolute path URL on iOS? That's really what the question is here.

Comment: @tribalvibes I've never worked with iOS, but I believe that something like `var/server/www/phonegap.0.9.5.js` should work