# iOS How i come back? What's the app's address?

Tags: ios, cordova

I have a phonegap + jquery mobile app. I have a login page and the form action go on my server. After the validation I have to come back on the app page. What's the link of my app? How can i go back?

Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

**Long story short:** I guess your app index page is at file://www/index.html

**Long story long:**

I'm not fully familiar with phonegap, but I assume you want to return to your phonegap page inside your app, right?

why not print out using javascript the window.location on this page? Something like:

```
alert(window.location);
```

and in order to perform the redirect after the login (in the server), you can either use some javascript in the result page to change window.location or send out a redirect in the headers with something like this (in case you're using php for your serverside):

```
<?php
header('Location: PUT-URL-HERE');
?>
```

also this question: [PhoneGap Relative URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288211/phonegap-relative-url) shows some internal urls inside a phonegap app

Comment: I solved my problem using ajax. The path that I get with "window.location" it's the path from the iPhone root and not the app root.
Thanks anyway for the answer